# How to treat empty string as null using retrofit2 with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2, json-deserialization

I am using `Retrofit2` with `Gson` to get a response from a public `API`.

The response looks something like this:

```
{"replies":[{"data":"value1"},{"data":"value2"}]}
```

but when the replies field is empty the data looks like this:

```
{"replies": ""}
```

So, if I treat replies like a string, I get an exception when I get an array. And when I treat it like an array I get an exception when I get an empty string.

Is there a way to resolve it so that I can ignore the value as if it is `null` when it is an empty string?

I would parse it manually but the actual response is huge and I would rather just use `Gson` than write a custom parse for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write custom deserialiser which in case of `JSON Array` deserialise it using `Gson` base deserialiser and in all other cases you can return `null` or empty list. Take a look on below example:

```
class RepliesJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Reply>> {

    @Override
    public List<Reply> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
            List<Reply> replies = new ArrayList<>(array.size());
            array.forEach(item -> replies.add(context.deserialize(item, Reply.class)));

            return replies;
        }

        // in all other case empty list or null
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

I assume that your `Pojo` looks like below (`Reply` is a name of item class on the list):

```
class Replies {

    @JsonAdapter(RepliesJsonDeserializer.class)
    private List<Reply> replies;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

As you can notice we use `@JsonAdapter` annotation to register our `RepliesJsonDeserializer` custom implementation. I suggest to return `Collections.emptyList()` always just to have clear code and avoiding `null`-checking.